# Loop through list or something else in a unique way

Tags: java, android

I need to create a method that takes a param as `maxValue`. And loop through it from 0 but once it uses one index, it must not use it again.

**Explanation:**

Lets take an example, `maxValue` is 2000. Now it should go from 0 to 2000 but the start index keeps change by other thread. Like it can be 0 again or it can be 1900 or 1999, can be any number less than `maxValue`. So it should keep loop from starting index to end and then loop for the rest of items.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public int i = 0;  //keep changes by other thread

public void DoStuff(int maxValue) {
    HashSet<Integer> valuesSet = new HashSet<Integer>();      

    // fill hashset
    for (int a = 0; a < maxValue; a++)
        valuesSet.add(a);       

    for (; i < maxValue; i++) {
        if (valuesSet.contains(i)) {
            valuesSet.remove(i);
            // SomeMethod(i);
        }

        if (valuesSet.isEmpty())// must check isEmpty first
            break;
        if (i == (maxValue - 1)) // reset i to 0 to use remaining items in hashset
            i = 0;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but I can see the problem will come if other thread keep set i to 0 or some less value than `maxValue` and this loop will go infinite. While it should be something better. Any idea guys?

Edited :
Deep Example
`i=0` and `maxValue=2000`

DoStuff gets called and when `i` reaches to 100 through loop, `i` got set by other thread to 1600, loop is keep going but again `i` got set to 30 by same other thread and then again and again it get set by other thread, Untill all the items in `valuesSet` get called in `SomeMethod(i)`. But problem is, if 1 or more item left in `valuesSet` like 1998 or 1999 and `i` keep get set to lower like 0 or 10 or 100, the loop has very low chances to break or finish.

What I want is, if once a number(0 to maxValue) get called in `SomeMethod`, it must not get called again, while the starting number keep changes and `SomeMethod` must have called with all numbers till maxValue. If `SomeMethod` get called till maxValue and still numbers left, it should start again with lowest number.

Comment: Is `i` used outside of the `DoStuff` method, besides being set by the threads?

Comment: `i` will be outside DoStuff, could be anywhere but outside.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track with using `valueSet` to record the arguments you've already passed to `SomeMethod`.  I don't think you've explained the rest of your requirements to the point where I understand them.

Comment: Is `i` changed by other threads while `DoStuff` is executing? Or is it on the next call to `DoStuff` that it needs to start at new value?

Comment: `i` keep changes no matter if DoStuff is executing or not :)

Comment: @KeithRandall, I have added another example

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clear, but it seems like you are describing something that should be implemented as custom `Iterator` class.  For example:

```
public class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int maxValue;
    private int pos;
    private List<T> list;
    public ListIterator(List<T> list, int maxValue) { 
        this.list = list; 
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public synchronized T next() {
        if (pos < list.size() && pos <= maxValue) {
            return list.get(pos++);
        } else {
            throw ...
        }
    }

    // etcetera.
}
```

You then provide an instance of this class to the specific threads that you want to be able to participate in the iteration.  Other threads won't be able to interfere.  Indeed other threads *could* use a different instance ... and iterate independently.

Note that the only differences between this custom iterator the one returned by `List.iterator()` are:

- This one only iterates from zero to maxValue.
- This one has `synchronized` methods so that it can be shared by multiple threads.

You could also add a `reset` method if that's what you need.